# Loop through files? grep

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I have 2 directories. I saved the name of the files in the second one in a temporary file. How do I loop over the files in the 1st directory and grep against the files in my temporary file?

```
find $2 -type f -name *.c > listafis.txt
for f in listafis.txt
   do
   if grep f $1
   then rm f
   fi
done
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Missing space? `-name *.c`.

Comment: I copied wrong. The idea is that I can't use grep to loop in a directory and I don't know what to use to loop through the files of a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop over a list of filenames in `listafis.txt` and test whether each exists in the current directory, then you need a *file existance test* rather than a `grep` command inside your loop, ex.

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  if [ -f "$1/${f##*/}" ]; then
    echo rm -- "$1/${f##*/}"
  fi
done < listafis.txt
```

`${f##*/}` is used here in place of `$f` to remove any leading path components. If you create `listafis.txt` without leading components, for example using

```
find "$2" -type f -name '*.c' -printf '%f\n' > listafis.txt
```

(note the use of quotes around `"$2"` to prevent word-splitting and around `'*.c'` to prevent premature expansion by the shell) then you can revert to plain `$f`.

Alternatively, you can avoid the intermediate file AND make the whole thing safe for arbitrary filenames (including those containing newlines) using

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  if [ -f "$1/$f" ]; then
    echo rm -- "$1/$f"
  fi
done < <(find "$2" -type f -name '*.c' -printf '%f\0')
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Thank you! It was very useful!!!!!!